# Question on example of a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Could anyone give me a non-trivial example (not the usual inner product) of a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, considering $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a diffrentiable manifold of dimension $n$?

As I knew, a Riemannian metric is a collection of inner products, each of which is defined on tangent space of a point on the manifold (for specific, $\mathbb{R}^n$). However, I do not know what a tangent space of a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

As a rather trivial example take some nonconstant function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ and let 
$$g(x)(v,w) := \phi(x) \langle v, w\rangle$$ 
(You can think of the tangent space $T_x \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a copy of $\mathbb{R}^n$ attached to the point $x$).

More generally, each smooth map $\psi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow Mat(n)^+$ of $\mathbb{R}^n $ into the set of positive definite matrices defines a metric by 
$$g(v,w): = v^t \psi(x)w$$
(with $v,w\in T_x \mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: Indeed, I was to but just use your immagination :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let be the following metric given by the following blockmatrix
$$g_{ij}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & \sin\vartheta_1\\
0 & I & 0\\
\sin\vartheta_1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
This is a nice metric that works out nicely in many calculations.

Comment: You should say what $\vartheta_1$ is.

Comment: Indeed, use your immagination :-)